# Не работает настройка цвета в ncurses

Tags: c, консоль, ncurses, curses

В моём терминале используется виртуальный терминал `xterm-256colors`, соответственно, цвет он поддерживает.

Пишу такую программу:

```c
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    curs_set(0);
    move(0, 0);
    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN);
    attrset(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    addstr("Red on green");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Вместо красной надписи на зелёном фоне выводится белая на чёрном. Почему так?

Comment: `start_color()` забыл вызвать...

Comment: Добавьте ответ на собственный вопрос, если он был решён

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед вызовом функции `init_pair(short,short,short)` необходимо вызвать функцию `start_color()`.
Без этого вызова цвета не будут отображаться, а если вызвать эту функцию после функции `init_pair`, то отображаться не будет вообще ничего (из-за установки атрибута `COLOR_PAIR(1)`). Благо в таком случае можно снова вызвать `init_pair` уже после `start_color`, и всё встанет на свои места. Дальнейшие вызовы `start_color` ни на что не влияют.

Comment: Лучше кусочек некрасивого, но работающего кода, чем десяток красивых слов. Вообщем, как по мне, вопрос лучше выглядит.

Comment: @0xdb я просто расписал все тонкости. Зачем тут код? Тем более, что он почти ничем не будет отличаться от кода в вопросе.